# Solving circuit with voltage and current sources in series

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG2Ynj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The only method I know I can solve with is superposition but that takes too long! Can you suggest some other methods that would be faster?

I need to know the currents entering the node between the 1 amp and the 3 resistors.

Comment: Sum of current at any node is 0

Comment: Despite the title of your question, there are no series connected voltage and current sources in your schematic.  Also, the pronoun "I" is, properly, capitalized.

Answer (score 2):

The systematic way to solve these kind of problems is nodal analysis (on which computer simulation programs are based ). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nodal_analysis

For each node you write down the equation that the sum of currents is zero. The voltages (with respect to a choosen ground) are the unknowns.

Note that the voltage sources need to be converted to current sources. If that is not possible (as in your case), the voltage between two nodes is known and one voltage can be eliminated.

In any case this will give you an equation system for the voltages, which can be solved. So this solves the circuit in more or less one step without superposition. 
It is also a systematic way, which requires (once understood) no thinking at all (well, correct calculation though).